# Copying an entry from a list into a table in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large list containing Personnel Names, Certification Names, and Certification Expiry Dates.

I am trying to write a script to copy the Certification Expiry Date for each entry into a table that has Personnel Names on one axis and Certification Names on the other axis.

The script needs to identify which cell in the table is the correct cell for each entry based on the Certification Name and Personnel Name, then copy the Certification Expiry Date into that cell.

I have written out step by step what needs to happen but am new to VBA so struggling to make it work.

Comment: Could you add sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a macro to do it.  Just use a pivot table:

[image]

If you really need VBA code (not very elegant, will submit it to CodeReview for improvement suggestions):

[image]

```
Sub PivotData()

    Dim rng As Range, cll As Range
    Dim arr As New Collection, a
    Dim var() As Variant
    Dim l As Long
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    l = 1

    Set rng = Range("A2:C7")

    ' Create unique list of names
    var = Range("A2:A7")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In var
        arr.Add a, a

    Next
    For l = 1 To arr.Count
        Cells(l + 1, 5) = arr(l)
    Next
    Set arr = Nothing

    ' Create unique list of certificates
    var = Range("B2:B7")
    For Each a In var
        arr.Add a, a
    Next
    For l = 1 To arr.Count
        Cells(1, 5 + l) = arr(l)
    Next
    Set arr = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

    Range("F2").FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(R2C3:R7C3,MATCH(1,((R2C1:R7C1=RC5)*(R2C2:R7C2=R1C)),0)),"""")"

    With Range("F2")
        lRow = .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        lCol = .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 4
    End With

    Range("F2:F" & lRow).FillDown
    Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lRow, lCol)).FillRight

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I use your VBA example if my source data has multiple other columns? For example it has columns A:M, but the data I want to use is in columns B, G, and L. 

Also I was hoping to have the data entered into a fixed table, rather than have excel generate the row and column labels like it does with a pivot table, how can I do this?

Comment: Change the input references AA to BB, BB to GG etc.  Also chage the references of the output table.You can have either a pivot table or cells populated by a macro.  Not quite sure how else I could help you.  Cheers,

Comment: Instead of using `Collection` for getting rid of duplicates, it's better to use `Dictionary` (I see, you use it everywhere where you eliminate duplicates).

Comment: Moreover, your style of adding `On Error Resume Next` doesn't allow you to catch other errors.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback.  I am looking forward to seeing your code I can learn from.  Regards,